# 'run vnc' command does not work on Kali!

Tags: metasploit

I am testing ms10_002_aurora exploit on my lab, everything is okay and I have reverse shell but the problem is when I type 'run vnc' it says that it transferred the VNC agent and executed that successfully, but the problem is that Kali does not bring the VNC viewer window for me, do you have any comment?

Comment: Here's my comment:  The problem you're facing is not a security issue but a problem running a VNC viewer and should therefore be addressed on a relevant site.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I thought maybe I missed some configuration in metasploit? or Kali?, Thanks

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Can you move my question or I should delete that, and post it on superuser?

Comment: Be patient. Users above 3,000 rep can cast "close votes" to move a question to another site. Once 4 more users have cast votes, it'll get moved automatically.

Comment: I disagree with all comments - I think this question belongs here.

Comment: I agree that this belongs here, but that there is not nearly enough information to go on. What have you tried? What does your packet captures say?

Comment: Also, I think you mean to say that `run vnc` doesn't work on metasploit, not Kali.

Comment: @schroeder 'run vnc' works and it says it has been successfully transferred the agent but the problem is that it does not bring vncviewer to show the victim desktop